# Show ribbon button in Dynamics CRM 2011, if metadata value is equal to a specific value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

is there a way to display a custom ribbon button only, if the value of a metadata attribute is equal to a specific value?

In my example I want only show a custom ribbon button on all forms, if the sharepoint documentmanagement is enabled for the current entity type.

For example:
I activated the sharepoint documentmanagement for the entity "account" but not for the entity "contact". If I am at the form for an account I want the crm to show the custom button. If I am at the form for a contact I want the crm NOT to show the custom button.

Best Regards and thank you,
Gerrit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way i can suggest is to use [CustomRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309433.aspx) that will enable/disable button instead hiding it ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334682.aspx) is more info about disable rules). Custom action could call jsript, which will execute [RetreiveEntityRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveentityrequest.aspx)  to verify is Sharepoint is Enabled for entity.

Normally you would use [EntityPropertyRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327898.aspx) from [ribbon display rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328560.aspx). Unfortunately SharePoint integration property is not among supported ones.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx) you can find more information how to customize ribbon